# How can one efficiently implement flattening and unflattening of neural network parameters in Axon (Elixir)?

Tags: neural-network, elixir, genetic-algorithm

To train a neural network with other optimization algorithms e.g Genetic Algorithms one needs to flatten the weights of the neural network into a vector, compute the updates using the vector weights then transform the weights back again into a format that the neural network can use. In `Axon` the weights/params are implemented as a map of `Nx` tensors. Ideally one would traverse the map in a depthwise version/recursively and flattening and combining the weights into a single vector. To implement the reverse of this one would need a way to keep track of the weight shapes, types and names. Then use that to rebuild the parameters map. I have a naive implementation of this that achieves the purpose. However, I am wondering if there is better way to achieve the same results without having to recreate tensors each time they are flattened or unflattened.
Here is my implementation:

```
defmodule Params do
  def flatten(params) do
    params
    |> to_flat_map()
    |> Map.values()
    |> Enum.reduce(fn x, acc ->
      Nx.concatenate([Nx.flatten(acc), Nx.flatten(x)])
    end)
  end

  def unflatten(params, template) do
    template
    |> Enum.reduce({%{}, -1, params}, fn {key, tensor_opts}, {params_map, idx, params} ->
      start_idx = idx + 1
      stop_idx = start_idx + Tuple.product(tensor_opts[:shape]) - 1

      opts = Keyword.take(tensor_opts, [:type, :names])
      curr_param = Nx.reshape(params[start_idx..stop_idx], tensor_opts[:shape], opts)
      params_map = Map.put(params_map, key, curr_param)

      {params_map, stop_idx, params}
    end)
    |> then(&elem(&1, 0))
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {k, v}, params_map ->
      put_in(params_map, Enum.map(String.split(k, "."), &Access.key(&1, %{})), v)
    end)
  end

  def extract_template(params) do
    params
    |> to_flat_map()
    |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> {k, [shape: Nx.shape(v), type: Nx.type(v), names: Nx.names(v)]} end)
    |> Enum.into(Map.new())
  end

  defp to_flat_map(params) when is_map(params) and not is_struct(params) do
    for {k, v} <- params, sub_key = to_string(k), sub_map <- to_flat_map(v), into: %{} do
      case sub_map do
        {key, val} -> {sub_key <> "." <> key, val}
        val -> {sub_key, val}
      end
    end
  end

  defp to_flat_map(params), do: [params]
end
```

For example consider this simple model:

```
model = 
  Axon.input({nil, 2}) 
  |> Axon.dense(2, activation: :relu) 
  |> Axon.dense(1, activation: :sigmoid)
```

With the following parameters obtained after calling `Axon.init` on the model:

```bash
%{
  "dense_0" => %{
    "bias" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84100>
      [0.0, 0.0]
    >,
    "kernel" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2][2]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84101>
      [
        [0.2250952422618866, -0.2300528585910797],
        [0.8318504691123962, 1.00990629196167]
      ]
    >
  },
  "dense_1" => %{
    "bias" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[1]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84102>
      [0.0]
    >,
    "kernel" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2][1]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84103>
      [
        [0.5544151663780212],
        [1.0918326377868652]
      ]
    >
  }
}
```

Calling `Params.flatten` on the parameters yields the following:

```bash
#Nx.Tensor<
  f32[9]
  EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84108>
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.2250952422618866, -0.2300528585910797, 0.8318504691123962, 1.00990629196167, 0.0, 0.5544151663780212, 1.0918326377868652]
>
```

The above vector can then be passed through the various operators of genetic algorithms such as crossover and mutation. After that to get prediction from the model, we need to convert the vector back to a map of weights for each of the layers. First we need a template/blueprint of the model's weights their shapes, types and names, which we can get by calling `Params.extract_template` and obtain:

```bash
%{
  "dense_0.bias" => [shape: {2}, type: {:f, 32}, names: [nil]],
  "dense_0.kernel" => [shape: {2, 2}, type: {:f, 32}, names: [nil, nil]],
  "dense_1.bias" => [shape: {1}, type: {:f, 32}, names: [nil]],
  "dense_1.kernel" => [shape: {2, 1}, type: {:f, 32}, names: [nil, nil]]
}
```

Then we can use the vector and the template and call `Params.unflatten` to obtain a map of weights that we can use with `Axon.predict`.

```bash
%{
  "dense_0" => %{
    "bias" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84109>
      [0.0, 0.0]
    >,
    "kernel" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2][2]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84111>
      [
        [0.2250952422618866, -0.2300528585910797],
        [0.8318504691123962, 1.00990629196167]
      ]
    >
  },
  "dense_1" => %{
    "bias" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[1]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84112>
      [0.0]
    >,
    "kernel" => #Nx.Tensor<
      f32[2][1]
      EXLA.Backend<host:0, 0.2002877735.2882928648.84114>
      [
        [0.5544151663780212],
        [1.0918326377868652]
      ]
    >
  }
}
```

The issue here is that at each step we create multiple tensors and we have to do the reshaping operations. For genetic algorithms this may be quite cumbersome as we have multiple solutions at each step. I would like to know how one can solve this issue of flattening and unflattening efficiently or is there an approach with Genetic Algorithms for neural networks where the weights do not have to be flattened?

Comment: Could you include sample input/output values so we can more easily see the desired transformation?

Comment: @Everett I have included sample input/output values